# How to emit a pyqtsignal through multi-threading task

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, concurrent.futures

I am trying to emit a pyqtsignal through multi-threading fashion. I created a function that performs the computations (e.g func). And another function that takes that task and run it in multiple threads (e.g Function).

The code works well when I use the parent thread. But, when I use the multiple threads, computations works well, but the signal is not emitted.

I need to use the multithreading, since the functions I am writing perform computational expensive tasks.

Please find below the sample code (I have used simple print function in this example)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot
import time
from threading import Thread
import sys
import math
import concurrent.futures


class Plot2D(QObject):
    finish=pyqtSignal(float)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Plot2D,self).__init__()

    def Function(self):
        st = time.time()

        # Using parent thread
        # self.func()

        # Using multi-thread 1
        #t=Thread(target=self.func)
        #t.start()
        #t.join()

        # Using multi-thread 2
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
           f = executor.submit(self.func)
        en = time.time()
        print(en-st)

    def func(self):
        n=10
        v=(1*100/(n-1))

        for i in range(n):
            print('thread')
            self.finish.emit(v)

    def fprint(self):
        print('works')

obj=Plot2D()
obj.finish.connect(obj.fprint)
obj.Function()
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. The actual code is very complicated so I tried to simplify it. So, the rest of the code is. when this signal is emitted a list is updated with emitted value. and a progressbar is updated using this value. So, in this case the progressbar is not updated.

Comment: When using parent thread, the progressbar is updated well

Comment: I have modified the code with explanation. WHen the signal emitted using self.func() the code will print (thread works thread works .......). But when it not emitted  using executor the code prints (thread thread ......). please check it

Comment: Yes, it working, I have modified it. please comment the parent thread and then comment the executor and run the code and you will see the difference using both

Comment: I see you have a lot of ignorance of how Qt works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be clear about the following concept: **The signals need an event loop for the signals to work.**

Considering the above, the solutions are:

- threading.Thread

You should not use join() because it blocks the main thread where the event-loop lives and because of the above the signals will not work.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from threading import Thread


class Plot2D(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

    def Function(self):
        Thread(target=self.func).start()

    def func(self):
        n = 10
        v = 1 * 100 / (n - 1)

        for i in range(n):
            print("thread")
            self.finished.emit(v)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def fprint(self):
        print("works")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Plot2D()
    obj.finished.connect(obj.fprint)
    obj.Function()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
thread
thread
thread
works
thread
works
thread
works
thread
thread
works
thread
works
thread
thread
works
works
works
works
works
```

- concurrent.futures

Do not use with since it will make the executor block the main thread (and we already know what problem it generates), it also calls `executor.shutdown(wait = False)`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import concurrent.futures


class Plot2D(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

    def Function(self):
        executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
        f = executor.submit(self.func)
        executor.shutdown(wait=False)

    def func(self):
        n = 10
        v = 1 * 100 / (n - 1)

        for i in range(n):
            print("thread")
            self.finished.emit(v)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def fprint(self):
        print("works")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Plot2D()
    obj.finished.connect(obj.fprint)
    obj.Function()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
thread
thread
works
thread
works
thread
works
thread
works
thread
thread
works
thread
works
thread
works
thread
works
works
works
```